# Getting items from objectstore returns [object Object] in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, indexeddb

Right now I'm looping through all objects in the object store "`tasksStore`". When I try to embed the objects into my HTML it only returns [object Object]. If I try to specify a part of the object to retrieve (for example `getTasks.result.title`) it returns undefined.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. When I console log the result I get the "normal" return of the object information:
[image].

I suspected that the datatypes of put and get is crashing, but after some digging it did not seem to be the issue.

## Javascript:

```
function listTask() {
    //open connection to database
    let request = window.indexedDB.open("KanbanDatabase", 2), 
    db,
    tx,
    store,
    index;

    //error handler on connection
    request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("There was en error listing tasks: " + e.target.errorCode);
    }

    //success handler on connection
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log("Successfully listed tasks");
        db = request.result;

        //define transaction, store and index
        tasksTx = db.transaction("tasksStore", "readwrite");
        tasksStore = tasksTx.objectStore("tasksStore");
        tasksIndex = tasksStore.index("title", "status");

        //error handler on result of the request
        db.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR " + e.target.errorCode);
        }

        //variable for counting objects in the index
        let amountOfTasks = tasksIndex.count();

        //error handler
        amountOfTasks.onerror = function() {
            console.log("There was an error finding the amount of tasks")
        }

        //success handler
        amountOfTasks.onsuccess = function() {
            //console.log("Tasks: " + amountOfTasks.result);
            //TODO: add destination to the function to be able to list tasks with the specific statuses
            for (var i = 0; i < amountOfTasks.result+1; i++) {
                let getTasks = tasksStore.get(i);

                let getTasksElementContainer = document.getElementById("list-tasks");
                let createTasksList = document.createElement("li");
                createTasksList.id = "task-" + i;
                
                getTasks.onerror = function() {
                    console.log("There was an error looping through the tasks")
                }

                getTasks.onsuccess = function() {
                    
                    console.log(getTasks.result);
                    getTasksElementContainer.appendChild(createTasksList);
                    createTasksList.innerHTML = getTasks.result;
                    //createTasksList.innerHTML = getTasks.result.title - does not work, returns undefined

                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(getTasks.result)` in getTasks.onsuccess function prints ?

Comment: It prints ```{taskID: 1, title: "Design kanban board for exam project", status: "backlog", tags: "Priority", dueDate: "2019-29-05", …}``` (as it should). The problem was not JSON stringifying the result, hence it returned [Object object]. Still not able to specify property though...

Comment: if `getTasks.result` returns an object then DOM will not decode it automatically.
you should try to check `typeof  `getTasks.result` if the type is object then you have to stringify it.

`var obj = { a: "1", title: "hello world" }
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
`

Comment: if `getTasks.result` is string type then you won't be able to access its properties. hense to access you can `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: The ```getTasks.result``` returns an object, yes, but ```getTasks.result.property``` returns ```Cannot read property 'property' of undefined at IDBRequest.getTasks.onsuccess```. Not sure why.

Comment: in that case you should check weather the 'property' is exists on that object or not.

getTasks.result.hasOwnProperty('property')

Comment: After some digging it seems like the ```i``` (```getTasks = tasksStore.get(i);```) in the for loop is the villain here. Replacing it with for example 1 (```getTasks = tasksStore.get(1);```) returns the property as expected. Not sure why this happens, as both return number when running typeof.

Comment: It means` getTasks` has some inbuilt prototypes to access data.
Have you tried ` var newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getTasks.result))` and then `console.log(newData. taskID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify`:

```
getTasksElementContainer.appendChild(JSON.stringify(createTasksList));
```

Comment: Thank you! This resolved the [Object object] problem. Do you have any idea why I'm not allowed to retrieve specifications (getTasks.result.title)? Error: ```Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at IDBRequest.getTasks.onsuccess```

Comment: can u add the exact object structure?

Comment: @PanosK - the exact object structure is: ({taskID: 1,
        title: "sometitle",
        status: "somestatus",
        tags: "sometag",
        dueDate: "somedate",
        description: "somedesc"});

Comment: After some digging it seems like the ```i``` (```getTasks = tasksStore.get(i);```) in the for loop is the villain here. Replacing it with for example 1 (```getTasks = tasksStore.get(1);```) returns the property as expected. Not sure why this happens, as both return number when running typeof.